# Externalize rendering of polymorphic objects

Tags: c++

Let's say we have a classical polymorphic architecture :

```
class Animal
{
    virtual void eat() = 0;
};

class Frog : public Animal
{
    virtual void eat() { ... }
};

class Chipmunk : public Animal
{
    virtual void eat() { ... }
};
```

This is fine. But when it comes to rendering, I could add a virtual `render` method to the `Animal` base class just like the `eat` method.

But then animals source files have dependencies to the particular library that is being used. This doesn't make things modulable and maintainable. Plus, their rendering code basically doesn't concern them.

What is a nice way of putting the render specific code out of the derived classes ?

When I say nice, I mean without using something like an overloaded method that returns a different number for each derived class so I can do a big *if...else if ...*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) - The virtual `render()` function is passed an instance of a `Visitor`, and then calls `Visitor.renderMe(this)`. Visitor then overloads `renderMe` as needed and contains the rendering specific code.

Comment: +1 This is exactly the problem the Visitor Pattern was meant to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Or check out the [Bridge Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern).

The animal classes could have a Render method, but rather than implementing the rendering methods to a particular API, you write them to an abstract rendering API.  Then you provide one or more concrete implementations of the rendering API.  Now the animal rendering is decoupled from the specific rendering technology, and both sides depend on a neutral, abstract API.

Answer (score 0):

Dependency injection.

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection

You can give the generic

```
Animal>>render()
```

the Renderer via parameter, then inside

```
Animal>>render(Renderer r)
```

call:

```
r.render(this).
```